# How to let user choose output file name in writecsv

Tags: r, csv

Any idea how to let the user choose the filename to save using this function ?

```
write.csv(tweets, file = "newfile.csv",
          row.names = TRUE, sep = ',', 
          col.names = TRUE)
```

Something like how we use the save as function and then a browser option appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [?file.choose](http://projetos.inpa.gov.br/i3geo/pacotes/r/win/library/utils/html/choose.files.html).  That should bring up the window that lets you navigate to the folder you want, and enter the file name you want to save under.  That is:

```
write.csv(tweets, file=file.choose(), row.names=TRUE, sep=',', 
          col.names=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use `choose.files()` to get a little more of the typical Windows "Save as" behavior:

1. Allow the user to define a filename which doesn't exist yet
2. Add a caption to the dialogue box
3. Default to .csv file type without the user having to type it

   ```
   write.csv(tweets, file=choose.files(caption="Save As...", 
             filters = c("Comma Delimited Files (.csv)","*.csv")))
   ```

Comment: according to `?choose.files` this function is only available on Windows