# File Manipulation: output file and prompt user for name on Windows

Tags: r, csv, output

I'm cringing just asking this here...  and likely searching by the wrong terms, so apologies if this is a redundant question.  How can I have a .R file create an output file and prompt the user for a file name, using an interactive dialog box?  Or more simply put a "Save As" prompt?

Basically the reverse of:

```
str <- "Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv)"
data <- read_csv(choose.files(multi = FALSE, filters = cbind(str, "*.csv")))
```

I want to use `write_csv()` and have the user to decide the name and directory.

Answer (score 1):

Solution comes from: [How to let user choose output file name in writecsv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335892/how-to-let-user-choose-output-file-name-in-writecsv)

```
str <- "Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv)"
write_csv(data, path = choose.files(caption = "Save As...",
                                  multi = FALSE, 
                                  filters = cbind(str, "*.csv")))
```

This produces the desired output. It prompts the user and filters files by only `.csv` extension.  If a file doesn't exist it will create it as`.csv` by default.